# How can I store orders with multiple products and quantity of each product in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've made a simple shopping cart with PHP and AJAX. You can add multiple products to it and you can set the quantity of each product.

It might be a silly question, but honestly, I don't really know how should I store these orders in the mysql database, with all the multiple products per order and the quantity of each product per order.

Can someone help me please?

EDIT: I learned a lot about databases, I know about relations, I just don't know how should I do this correctly.

Comment: A single product can be in many orders and a single order can hold many products. This is called a *Many To Many* relation. This can help your searches

Answer (score 1):

You should use aggregation table

That means, you have to create a table where primary key is combination of 2 foreign keys, one is a primary key of `order`, 2nd is primary key of `product`
and then, you have extra fields in table like `count`

That means you have a unique key for each row in table, because it is combination of order and product

But I have to say, this is literally basic knowledge of SQL databases

Answer (score 0):

1 Create a PRODUCTS table with a PRODUCT_ID as primary key.
2 Create a ORDERS table with a ORDER_ID as primary key.
3 Create a ORDER_LINES table with foreign keys ORDER_ID and PRODUCT_ID.
The latter will have a column QUANTITY.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have Products Table that contains the following columns
(ProductID, ProductName, Qty). and you want to sell many products to many customers. a many-to-many relationship in the database, you just need to add two more tables to your database.
The first table and let's assume it's called [Cart] in which you're going to store the Cart ID, Customer ID.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cart](
CartID int NOT NULL, 
CreatedDate datetime NULL,  --to get the current date and time
CustomerID int NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CartID)
)
```

The second table and let's assume it's called Cart_Detail in which we're going to store the ordered products and the quantity of each product.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cart_Detail](
LineID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CartID int NULL,                  
ProductID int NULL,               
Price decimal(18, 2) NULL,        
Qty int NULL,
Amount decimal(18, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

LineID column is to facilitate the creation of views and operations such as selecting, updating, or deleting a specific product